# Change UITableViewCell height even if cells count is 0

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` and want the cells to have a height of 40. When there is at least one cell, the following delegate method works:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    return 40.0f;
}
```

If there are no cells, the empty cells have the default height. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to also make sure you set the `rowHeight` on the table view in viewDidLoad:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = 40.0f;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are also able to set the property with in a storyboard, under the ruler looking icon on the right side, is tableview size, under that is row height which you can set there

Comment: @Aaron's answer helps me. I wanted to do this programmatically, so my question has been answered

Comment: yes, i thought i would throw this in, incase other people view the post